# Vanilla JS - Reinitializing functions after swup.js page transition

Tags: javascript

I'm fairly new to JS and am using swup.js (an awesome library btw) to transition between pages on a site. Transitions are working well however post-transition I need to re-initalise some JS functions I have.

According to swup.js docs I just to wrap them in a swup event. How would I do this in the below scenario? I think I specifically need to re-add the two functions to the two buttonLeft/buttonRight constants.

Examples here: https://swup.js.org/getting-started/reloading-javascript

```
//JS in script tag at bottom of body
    const swup = new Swup();
        init();
        swup.on('contentReplaced', init);


// Function called in my main.js file
function init() {
    if (document.querySelector('')) { // What do I include here?
        // What do I include here?
    }


// Functions I'd like reinitialized (also in main.js)
const buttonRight = document.getElementById('slide-right');
const buttonLeft = document.getElementById('slide-left');
buttonLeft.onclick = scrollLeft; 
buttonRight.onclick = scrollRight;

function scrollLeft() {
  document.getElementById('hoz-scroller').scrollTo({ left: 0, behavior: 'smooth' }); 
  buttonLeft.classList.add('disabled'); 
  if (buttonRight.classList.contains('disabled')) { 
    buttonRight.classList.remove('disabled'); 
  }
};

function scrollRight() {
  document.getElementById('hoz-scroller').scrollTo({ left: elementWidth, behavior: 'smooth' }); 
  buttonRight.classList.add('disabled'); 
  if (buttonLeft.classList.contains('disabled')) { 
  buttonLeft.classList.remove('disabled'); 
  }
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answered my own question. Thanks to these guys: https://openclassrooms.com/en/courses/3523231-learn-to-code-with-javascript/4379006-use-constructor-functions. Answer for all those other noobs if they need it below:

Basically, you need to wrap the seperate functions in a new function and call that in the swup init function:

```
function init() {
    if (document.querySelector('#hoz-scroller')) { //This checks if this element is on the the page (in the html)
        new scrollers(); // If it is then it creates a new instance of the 'scrollers' function
    }
}
var scrollStart = new scrollers(); // This initialises the below function the first time (first page load not controlled by swup)

function scrollers() { // This it the wrapper funtion

  const element = document.getElementById("hoz-scroller"); 
  const elementRect = element.getBoundingClientRect(); 
  const elementWidth = elementRect.width;  
  const elementMiddle = (elementWidth / 2 - 50); 
  element.scrollTo(elementMiddle, 0); 

  const buttonRight = document.getElementById('slide-right'); 
  const buttonLeft = document.getElementById('slide-left');
  buttonLeft.onclick = scrollLeft; 
  buttonRight.onclick = scrollRight;

  function scrollLeft() {
    document.getElementById('hoz-scroller').scrollTo({ left: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });  
    buttonLeft.classList.add('disabled'); 
    if (buttonRight.classList.contains('disabled')) { 
      buttonRight.classList.remove('disabled'); 
    }
  };
  function scrollRight() {
    document.getElementById('hoz-scroller').scrollTo({ left: elementWidth, behavior: 'smooth' }); 
    buttonRight.classList.add('disabled'); 
    if (buttonLeft.classList.contains('disabled')) { 
    buttonLeft.classList.remove('disabled');
    }
  };
};
```